# Overwrite the values in an associative array of null values with another associative array with integer values

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, default-value, overwrite

I have an associative array of the states of some country, and the states names are the keys:

```
array:13 [
  "Ontario" => null
  "Manitoba" => null
  "New Brunswick" => null
  "Yukon" => null
  "Saskatchewan" => null
  "Prince Edward Island" => null
  "Alberta" => null
  "Quebec" => null
  "Nova Scotia" => null
  "British Columbia" => null
  "Nunavut" => null
  "Newfoundland and Labrador" => null
  "Northwest Territories" => null
]
```

And I have another associative array that contains all states that have values:

```
array:8 [
  "Alberta" => 17
  "Cairo" => 1
  "Calgary" => 1
  "ddd" => 4
  "gfdxf" => 1
  "New Cairo" => 1
  "Ontario" => 1
  "secret" => 30
]
```

Now I need to map the second array to the first one so that the result would be:

```
array:13 [
  "Ontario" => 1
  "Manitoba" => 0
  "New Brunswick" => 0
  "Yukon" => 0
  "Saskatchewan" => 0
  "Prince Edward Island" => 0
  "Alberta" => 17
  "Quebec" => 0
  "Nova Scotia" => 0
  "British Columbia" => 0
  "Nunavut" => 0
  "Newfoundland and Labrador" => 0
  "Northwest Territories" => 0
]
```

I created a nested loop and it works fine, but the code is very ugly, now is there a more efficent way to do it?

My code:

```
foreach ($all_states as $state_x => $value_x) {
            
    foreach ($country_states as $state_y => &$value_y) {
    
        if (strtolower($state_x) == strtolower($state_y)) {

            $value_y = $value_x;
        } elseif ($value_y == NULL) {

            $value_y = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have working code which you would like to improve on, then the StackExchange Code Review might be a better place for your question - please check their guidelines. Here we really only deal with problems with code, or questions about specific programming details. "It works but I think it's ugly" isn't really that kind of problem. If by "efficient" you're talking about performance in terms of execution time or memory use then we could maybe help, but if you just want to make the code "nicer" then that's more of a code review issue IMHO.

Comment: No not just nicer, I've that problem not just in one case, it happens more than once, in the project, So I needed a more efficient way in case of large inputs, But thanks for the advice, I didn't know about StackExchange Code Review

Comment: "I've that problem"...what problem? What's the issue with "large" inputs? If you need help on that particular issue please could you be more specific about it.

Comment: `array_merge` but the `null` values will still be `null` and not `0`.

Comment: You can do that with either `foreach` loop or combination of `array_merge` and `array_map` - I show both ways in my post - feel free to choose the one the seem better for you

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: Your code [doesn't appear to work as desired](https://3v4l.org/h5ZMo)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how the performance would compare, but you could use something like this, which I think looks a bit cleaner:

```
foreach ($all_states as $state => $value) {
  if (isset($country_states[$state])) {
    $all_states[$state] = $country_states[$state];
  } else {
    $all_states[$state] = 0;
  }
}

// If you are running a recent PHP version you could shorten this further
foreach ($all_states as $state => $value) {
  $all_states[$state] = $country_states[$state] ?? 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done simpler with 1 `foreach` loop as:

```
$countriesArr = .... // consider this the array with NULL
$countriesDataArr = ... // consider this to be the array with the values 

foreach( $countriesArr as $k => &$v) {
    $v = isset($countriesDataArr[$k]) ? $countriesDataArr[$k] : 0;            
}
```

You can also use [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)as:

```
$res = array_map(function($v){return 0;}, $countriesArr);
$res = array_merge($countriesArr, $countriesDataArr);
```

As the second array will override the first keys:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one.

The `array_map` will convert all the values of the `NULL` to 0

Answer (score 1):

You can walk the array and map the other values to it or set to `0` if it doesn't exist:

```
array_walk($all_states, function(&$v, $k) use($country_states) {
                            $v = $country_states[$k] ?? 0;
                        });
```

However I would just merge and either keep the `null` values or cast to integer:

```
$all_states = array_map('intval', array_merge($all_states, $country_states));
```

You could also get `0`s like this:

```
$all_states = array_merge(array_flip(array_keys($all_states)), 
                          $country_states);
```

Or like this:

```
$all_states = array_merge(array_fill_keys(array_keys($all_states), 0), 
                          $country_states);
```

Answer (score 1):

Swap the values of your first array to 0, and then replace values from the second array into the first:

```
<?php

$clothes = 
[
    'hats' => null,
    'shirts' => null,
    'trousers' => null,
    'pants' => null
];

$values = 
[
    'shirts' => 10,
    'hats' => 2
];

var_export(
    array_replace(
        array_fill_keys(array_keys($clothes), 0),
        $values
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'hats' => 2,
    'shirts' => 10,
    'trousers' => 0,
    'pants' => 0,
)
```